# Does OS X Lion provide OpenCL image support for Radeon 5770?

Tags: image, macos, opencl, osx-lion, ati

On OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8), OpenCL image support is not available on my Mac Pro with Radeon 5770 graphics card.  Indeed this is believed to be common to all AMD/ATI Radeon cards under Snow Leopard and earlier.  Specifically:

```
  clGetDeviceInfo(cdDevices[uiDeviceUsed], CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT, sizeof(g_bImageSupport), &g_bImageSupport, NULL);
```

results in g_bImageSupport being false.

I want to know if anyone who has the final release 10.7 (Lion) and a Radeon 5770 graphics card in a Mac Pro, can check to see if CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT now returns true for this hardware?

An easy test is to download the Apple sample code for the raytraced Quarternion Julia-Set:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OpenCL_RayTraced_Quaternion_Julia-Set_Example/Introduction/Intro.html

and build it and run it.  The output on my system is sadly:

```
Connecting to AMD ATI Radeon HD 5770...
Qjulia requires images: Images not supported on this device.
```

Hope to hear that this now works in Lion ...

- David.

Comment: I don't have a 5770 but I do have a 5870. Is it of any value for me to test that out for you?

Comment: Coxy - absolutely yes please!  It would be feasible to upgrade to the 5870 if that works, although I'd have to compare the cost to going back to an NVIDIA Q4000.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Lion 10.7.1 with a Radeon 5770 and the given example works great (yay!), running around 150fps.  So... yay!

Answer (score 1):

For me it works fine with ATI Radeon 5870. Initial figure running around 290fps. The example requires 10.7 to run.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I'm running 10.7 with a Radeon 5870. The sample app can connect to the card and renders the "thing" fine.

Comment: Great - thanks Coxy.  I still hope someone else can advise on the 5770, but this is an excellent start :-)